# 1000th files failed to create in Window Mobile OS with could not evaluate expression error

Tags: c#, mobile, window, .net-cf-3.5

I appreciate any help.

I'm using a handheld device running on **Window mobile 6.1 OS**. I developed an C#.net application using **.net compact framework** to create 1000 of file with identical filename but different counter eg. 30.6.2015.test123.1.txt -> 30.6.2015.test123.1000.txt

```
                try
                {
                  TextWriter tw = null;
                  DateTime dtmCurrent = DateTime.Now;
                  String path = @"\Mounted Volume\gan3\";
                  for (int i = 1; i < 1500; i++)
                  {
                    tw = new StreamWriter(path + "22.6.2015.test123." + i + ".txt", true);
                    tw.Close();
                  }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine(err.StackTrace);
                }
```

The program throw exception **Could not evaluate expression** when create the 1000th file. There is no problem for creating files from 1st to 999th.

Anyone can tell what is the cause of this error? is the bugs from the framework itself?

Comment: Seems to be screaming out as a length overflow, but can't see anything at all obvious there. Have you tried manually creating a file with that 30.6.2015.test123.1000.txt filename?

Comment: Hi Endareth, thanks for your reply. Still failed to manually create a file with the filename u suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Mobile for Pocket PC, Windows Mobile for Smartphone, Windows CE Platform Note:

Windows CE cannot store more than 999 files in a directory when the files share the same short file name (that is, the eight-character name, period (.), and 3-character extension). The workaround is to ensure that the short file names are different. For example, if the files are named Longfilename0001.txt through Longfilename1000.txt, place the number at the beginning of the file name instead of at the end.